# Tag selector causes scrolling within the page

Tags: bug, design

The tag selector on this site and its Meta causes the content container to scroll in Chrome/Firefox, which isn't desired:

[image]

Comment: Our containers are all messed up in review as well - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163548/the-mod-link-under-the-review-tools-fails-to-work-on-safari-6 and http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/moderator-tools-from-the-review-pane-are-broken

Comment: Also, I'm not able to reproduce this on Safari 6 so either I have a different view as a moderator or it's browser specific.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this or is this a candidate for declining to send to the developers as a bug?